# tell me why encodePacked not working

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

```
pragma solidity 0.8.13;
contract A {
    function callBFunction( address _address) public returns (bool) {
        bytes4 sig = bytes4(keccak256("bFunction()"));
        (bool success,) = _address.call(
            abi.encodePacked(sig)
        );
        return success;
    }
}
contract B {
    uint256 public num = 4;
    function bFunciton()  public returns(uint256){
        num = 996;
        return num;
    }
}
```

**run A.callBFunction After that, the num of the B contract has not changed.**

Answer (score 0):

You have write wrong the function name in A smart contract.
In this line of code:

```
 bytes4 sig = bytes4(keccak256("bFunction()"));
```

your function inside B smart contract is not called `bFunction()` but `bFunciton()`.

Change the function name in line, that I described above, and it'll work.